# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I am not sure why, but for some reason in my app when I call AdView.loadAd(AdRequest), my app outputs `W/Ads: Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing.` and then crashes with the 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.` even though in my xml layout file I have defined `adSize`.
Any Suggestions?

**XML Layout File**

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="****************" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
    AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
    ad.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Ad size and Banner id programmatically, before call `loadAd()` method:

```
AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
//Set the Ad Size    
ad.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
 //Set the Banner Id
ad.setAdUnitId(YOUR_BANNER_ID);    
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        ad.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Change your layout to:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer fixes the crashing problem but for some reason the ad banner is showing: Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing.

Comment: be sure to add set the adSize: ad.setAdUnitId(YOUR_BANNER_ID);    and build your project again! =)

Comment: hmm I have added ad.setAdUnitId(YOUR_BANNER_ID); but for some reason, it is still displaying Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing.

Comment: @ChristopherZhou I have the same issue "Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing" how did you fix it?